# After upgrading to Gradle 2.0: Could not find property 'Compile' on root project

Tags: java, gradle

To avoid warnings regarding special characters when building my Java source code, I put this line in my `gradle.build` which worked fine before upgrading to Gradle 2.0:

```
tasks.withType(Compile) { options.encoding = "UTF-8" }
```

After upgrading, this fails with the following error:

```
Could not find property 'Compile' on root project
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Changing the line to

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) { options.encoding = "UTF-8" }
```

fixed the issue.

Comment: `Compile` had long been deprecated in favor of `JavaCompile`, and was finally removed in 2.0.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser: Good to know, thanks. I didn't notice that because I wasn't getting any deprecation warnings when compiling with Gradle pre 2.0.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser how do I set encoding for all compile tasks (not just java)? It used to be ```Compile```, should I use ```tasks.withType(AbstractCompile)``` instead?

Comment: `Compile` has been renamed to `JavaCompile`. To set the encoding for Groovy sources, use `tasks.withType(GroovyCompile) { groovyOptions.encoding = "UTF-8" }`. For Scala sources, use `tasks.withType(ScalaCompile) { scalaCompileOptions.encoding = "UTF-8" }`. There never was an easier way.

Answer (score 2):

For Groovy based projects. It'd be:

```
tasks.withType(GroovyCompile) {
    options.debug = true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `task.withType(JavaCompile)`.

My code:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-tomcat-plugin:2.2.3'
    }

  tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
      options.debug = true
      options.debugOptions.debugLevel = "source,lines,vars"
      options.encoding = "UTF-8"
  }
}
```

Comment: While this may solve the OP question, please add only essential parts of code, and provide explanation.